# How to stop your YouTube comments/activities from showing on Google+

Tags: youtube, google-plus, privacy

I don't want anyone know what videos I’m watching/liking/commenting or any of my activity from YouTube to show on my Google+ page or stream.

I found a few settings on the privacy page:

[image: privacy page screenshot-youtube]

But I can't find any settings for comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: [You don't have to do anything](http://youtube-global.blogspot.com/2015/07/youtube-comments.html).

> The comments you make on YouTube will now appear only on YouTube, not also on Google+

---

The only YouTube activity that gets posted to Google+ is comments. To stop that from happening simply uncheck "Also share to Google+" when commenting.

[image]